# Overriding the run method

Tags: java

```
class Car extends Vehicle { 
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Car().run(); 
     }
     private final void run() {
         System.out.println("Car");
     }
 }

class Vehicle {
     private final void run() {
         System.out.println("Vehicle");
     }
 }
```

This is a practice question in "SCJP exam for J2SE 5 platform"
It returns Car apparently.

But Car extends Vehicle and overrides run(). But run in superclass is final. I didnt think you could override final methods?

Comment: who says it has been overridden?

Comment: "In some situations, you might need to change the behavior of an inherited method, such as when implementing polymorphism,.... In that case, you would redefine the method by keeping the same signature but rewriting the body. This is exactly what is called method overriding"

Comment: Hasnt the run method kept the same signature, but changed the body?

Comment: Yes, I totally understand what overriding is.  In Car, if you called `super.run()` - what happens?

Comment: Vehicle would be returned

Comment: why don't you try it, rather than guessing.  As per the accepted answer `A private method is not visible anywhere outside itself and therefore can not be overridden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret lies within the `private` modifier. [JLS 8.4.3.3. final Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3)

> A private method and all methods declared immediately within a final class (§8.1.1.2) behave as if they are final, since it is impossible to override them.

A private method is not visible anywhere outside itself and therefore can not be overridden.

They just happen to have the same name but they don't share anything beyond.

This behavior also makes a lot of sense if you extend a class you don't know in sourcecode. You would need to know all the private method signatures you can't see so you don't accidentally override and break them.

Comment: Gotcha! That does make sense. Ta

Comment: Even worse, you may have a superclass, and you want to refactor the class body by, for example, taking some duplicated code and turning it into a private method.  It would be a real problem if you had to find every possible subclass of your superclass and look at all the subclass's methods, in order to figure out a method name that couldn't conflict with any of them.  You need to be able to change _implementation details_ independently--that's one of the purposes of OOP, and allowing private methods to be overridden would completely break that.

Answer (score 0):

Important to note that.

```
 private final void run() {
     System.out.println("Car");
 }
```

private can be accessed within a Car class and in Vehicle class you have declared method as final. Final is a keyword where you can't override to other class, though if you create an object reference for Vehicle. So newCar().run() will access will print the output as "Car". Here override concept will not be applicable.